# email parser in c++

Tags: c++, parsing

I would like some help with this email parser, if possible.

This code has all of its proper declaration and initialization, but I'm not sure where I am messing up this loop:

```
  while ( getline( fin, lines ) )
  {
     for ( int i = 0; i < lines.length( ); i++ )
     {
        if ( lines[ i ] == '@' )
        {
           for ( s = i; s < lines.length( ); s-- )
           {
              if ( s < 0 )
              {
                 break;
              }
              if ( validChar( lines[ s ] ) == false )
              {
                 break;
              }
           } //for

           for ( e = i; e > lines.length( ); e++ )
           {
              if ( e == lines.length( ) )
              {
                 break;
              }
              if ( validChar( lines[ e ] ) == false )
              {
                 break;
              }
              if ( lines[ e ] == '.' )
              {
                 hasDot = true;
              }
           } // for

           anEmail = lines.substr( s, e );

           cout << anEmail << endl;
        }
     } // if
  }    // while
```

And this is for the function:

```
  bool validChar( char a )
  {
     bool result = false;
     if ( a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z' || a >= 'a' && a <= 'z' || a >= '0' && a <= '9' || a == '.' || a == '-' || a == '+' )
     {
        result = true;
     }
     return result;
  }
```

EDIT: a test case being this string in a text file "this is an email file with DummyTest@my.test and some other text for the test", I want this "DummyTest@my.test", and I'm only getting this "@my.test and some other text for the test"

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: May I suggest you try to improve the indenting a little? It's quite hard to read, especially since you have so much code inside the outer `for` loop.

Comment: Can you give some example input and expected output?

Comment: Present a [testcase](http://sscce.org) or we're guessing (which I don't intend to spend my time doing!).

Comment: Fixed the indenting, don't believe I messed up the logic while doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
       for ( s = i; s < lines.length( ); s-- )
       {
          //...
          if ( validChar( lines[ s ] ) == false )
          {
             break;
          }
       } //for
```

You're checking if `lines[s]` is valid to decide whether to terminate; but `lines[s] == '@'` initially, since you just found the `@`! If you initialize `s` to `i - 1`, you'll be closer... but then you'll discover that your `substr` has a bunch of off-by-ones in it. You'll end up needing to do `anEmail = lines.substr( s + 1, e + 1 );`

But that will just cause the code to past your test cases. This is not a valid approach to parsing e-mail addresses. This approach will not work on all valid e-mail addresses, including `"an@sign"@foo` and `"spaces are legal only in quotes"@foo`. You'll also want to extend validChar to deal with the actual set of valid characters, which varies for the name and domain; `!#$%&'*+-/=?^_{}|~@[IPv6:2001:db8:1ff::a0b:dbd0]` is perfectly legal. Finally, if it's important to you to actually rule out illegal addresses, you'll again be restricted by this approach: `double..dot@foo` is not legal, nor is `double@at@foo`.

The source for this is RFC822 (or it's much newer siblings RFC5322 and RFC6531), where you'll discover that a regular expression cannot parse e-mails, as `name(comment(comment))@foo` is legal, while `name(comment))@foo` is not.

Comment: I have read your previous comment, and I will edit it but after I have solved the problem at hand. (otherwise a long list of problems never being finished)